# HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error on Glassfish

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, ubuntu-14.04, glassfish-4

I recently changed my domain SSL certificate since the old one was expiring. The certificate was successfully installed on glassfish and I my application was up and running. 
The challenge comes in whenever I log in to glassfish admin console , I get "**HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error**" . I use ubuntu 14.04 server.
[image]

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem after updating the SSL-certificate on my servers...

After I run the following command in the admin console I was able to login:

```
asadmin enable-secure-admin
```