# error 500 for glassfish

Tags: java, ubuntu, glassfish, ssl-certificate

I am facing the same problem as mentioned in this question

[HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error on Glassfish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41735106/http-status-500-internal-server-error-on-glassfish)

I do this

```
root@user1:~# asadmin enable-secure-admin
No command 'asadmin' found, did you mean:
 Command 'amadmin' from package 'amanda-server' (universe)
 Command 'acsadmin' from package 'ion' (universe)
asadmin: command not found
```

I have a Linux 16.04 and

tried this and i got another email. I appreciate if you can comment on this

```
glassfish4/bin/asadmin enable-secure-admin
remote failure: At least one admin user has an empty password, which secure admin does not permit. Use the change-admin-password command or the admin console to create non-empty passwords for admin accounts.
Command enable-secure-admin failed.
```

Comment: The error is clear: there is at least one admin user with an empty password. You should edit this user's password. A user with an empty password is not a secure user. And generally an administrator with an empty password is a critical issue.

Comment: @BackSlash can you please tell me how to do that ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619063/glassfish-3-1-1-how-to-enable-secure-admin-for-different-domains#answer-26253653

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the password of admin this way:

```
asadmin --host localhost --port 4848 change-admin-password
```

It will prompt you with user, type "admin", admin password, retype admin password

Once this is done, enable the security with the following command:

```
asadmin --host localhost --port 4848 enable-secure-admin
```

This should fix the problem.

Resource Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12323491/2293534

Comment: glassfish4/bin/asadmin --host localhost --port 4848 change-admin-password
Enter admin user name [default: admin]>admin
Enter the admin password> 
Enter the new admin password> 
Enter the new admin password again> 
Authentication failed for user: admin (Usually, this means invalid user name and/or password)
Command change-admin-password failed.

Comment: I use admin as user and password as password

Comment: @nik The previous error is telling that the admin user has an empty password, so this means that the first password prompt must be left blank

Comment: `Enter the admin password>` will be blank. Then you will give `Enter the new admin password>` as "password" `Enter the new admin password again>` as "password:"

Comment: @SkyWalker I did that and I stoped the server and I restart my computer. Now it does not connect at all !!!!  nik@mour:~$ glassfish4/bin/asadmin start-domain
Waiting for domain1 to start ................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: @SkyWalker sure, I appreciate your help. Now It does not connect I don't know why, if you have time and you can, I can even give you access using teamvierw however, I appreciate your comment to know why it is not working anymore ?

Comment: Run this command now `asadmin --host localhost --port 4848 restart-domain`

Comment: @SkyWalker should I do it as root? my mean i go to 'sudo -i' or as a user I can do that too?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137840/discussion-between-skywalker-and-nik).